# Can we fetch the call details of an iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios4, jailbreak

Can we fetch the call details like dialed numbers, missed calls of an iPhone?

**UPDATE**

Can we do it in jail broken phones for CYDIA store?

Comment: It is possible on a jailbroken phone - don't ask me how to do it though.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Can you tell me the reason behind not revealing the details?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do it for jailbroken device.

The call history is stored in call_history.db.

Comment: How can I access that particular file. Is there any specific private API that should be used ? Or can it be queried as a typical db file?

Comment: The entire path is /private/var/wireless/Library/CallHistory/call_history.db

Answer (score 2):

No - Apple simply don't provide an API to do this.

Comment: Can we do it in jail broken phones for CYDIA store?

Answer (score 2):

No, no information about phone calls is available, nor SMS messages.

iOS apps are sandboxed to prevent developers from doing nasty things like sending that data back to their servers. It limits some potentially cool apps, but it also protects privacy.

Comment: Can we do it in jail broken phones for CYDIA store?

Comment: Yes, as KingofBliss noted, you can.

Answer (score 0):

Yes,You can't do with non-Jail Broken iphones. If you want to do that,you must have a jail broken iphone. API is not providing any private API to access their APplication SANDBOx.Apple will never provide due to security.